# Having error while using laravel-mix in mix.sass();

Tags: laravel, sass, laravel-mix, bulma

> I'm experiencing this error. Can you help me with this. using laravel-mix

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/main.scss', 'public/css/app.css');
```

Issue here :

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                                                                                                                                                                                             9:38:15 AM
 error  in ./resources/assets/sass/main.scss

Module build failed:
@import "node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/intial-variables.sass";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/intial-variables.sass.
Parent style sheet: stdin



error  in ./resources/assets/sass/main.scss
Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed:
@import "node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/intial-variables.sass";
```

> I'm not used to using sass, but It is a requirement for me, so that
>   I can save some time in customizing the app's look and feel. So these
>   are my customization.

```
// fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Roboto+Slab');

@import "node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/intial-variables.sass";

@import 'variables.scss';
@import 'node_modules/bulma.sass';
```

> variables.scss

```
$edgewater : #c0dfd9 ;
$green-white: #E9ECE5;
$submarine: #b3c2bf ;
$tuatara : #3b3a36 ;


$body-background : $submarine ;
$primary  : $edgewater ;
$primary-invert : $tuatara;
$family-serif : 'Roboto Slab', 'Open Sans' , 'serif' ;


$text : #tuatara;
$text-light : $green-white ;
$family-primary : $family-serif ;
```

Comment: You have a typo - `initial-variables.sass`

Comment: I believe adding the sass/scss extension isn't a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`@import "../../../node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/intial-variables.sass";`

Your "import" should be a relative path from the "main.scss" file.